# Responsive Divs are overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a code at http://jsfiddle.net/N7nj5/

CSS:

```
/* ================================================================ Pre-footer Advert pfa =========================================================== */
#pre-footer-ad-container {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}

.pre-footer-ad {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.sectionpfa {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.colpfa {
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.colpfa:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.grouppfa:before,
.grouppfa:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.grouppfa:after {
    clear:both;
}
.grouppfa {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}           

/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.pfaspan_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}
.pfaspan_1_of_2 {
    width: 49.5%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .colpfa { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .pfaspan_2_of_2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .pfaspan_1_of_2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* ================================================================ Footer Content ================================================================ */
#footer-container {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color:#16a085;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer {
    width: 95%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left:2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    background-color:#16a085;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.sectionfooter {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.colfooter {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}
.colfooter:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.groupfooter:before,
.groupfooter:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.groupfooter:after {
    clear:both;
}
.groupfooter {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}



/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.footerspan_3_of_3 {
    width: 23%;
}
.footerspan_2_of_3 {
    width: 24%;
}
.footerspan_1_of_3 {
    width: 49%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .colfooter { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .footerspan_3_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .footerspan_2_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .footerspan_1_of_3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Pre-Footer Advertisement pfa -->
    <div id="pre-footer-ad-container">
        <div class="pre-footer-ad">
            <div class="sectionpfa grouppfa">
                <div class="colpfa pfaspan_1_of_2">
                    This is column 1
                </div>
                <div class="colpfa pfaspan_1_of_2">
                    This is column 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer Content -->
    <div id="footer-container">
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="sectionfooter groupfooter">
                <div class="colfooter footerspan_1_of_3">
                    Testimonials
                </div>
                <div class="colfooter footerspan_2_of_3">
                    Legal
                </div>
                <div class="colfooter footerspan_3_of_3">
                    Other Links
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Problem Definition:

There are two parts:
 1. the columns in red color
 2. the column in torquise color

They are responsive.
When I reduce the width of the screen, the red ones overlap the torquise one.

I DONT WANT THAT TO HAPPEN!!!

I want that when the site is displayed on a mobile screen, the red and torquise regions should not overlap.

Currently when i reduce the screen resolution, the red ones come one below the other, which is perfect. but the same should happen with the torquise one also.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the footer-container

```
#footer-container {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color:#16a085;
    color: #ffffff;
    clear: both; /* <--- */
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/N7nj5/2/)**

Comment: gr8!!! Thanks a ton @Danield...
It worked. and just if i want the distance between both to be a little more, how can i achieve that?

Comment: increase the margin like: `margin-to: 60px`

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-height` for test instead height, or reset `height` too via your queries.

Tes with `min-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/N7nj5/1/